# Multi Language Website, Two Masterpages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I designed a website in two languages, English & Arabic. Since Arabic language takes the direction: RTL I had to make another master-page for it, therefore I copied the code again and did some CSS editing and rewrote it in Arabic. Now I have two folders (Oriented EN) and (Oriented AR). I've been told that I have to put (Oriented AR) in the English version folder, but I assume that there will be problems so I want to know how can I put Arabic folder into English folder and create a link on top of the Website so that it links between the two master-pages, so when I click it it'll switch to other language.

Comment: have you used any cms or framework or just plain html page?

Comment: If you are using .net, you can create App_LocalResourses for multi language. No need to duplicate pages.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2012, I've made an ASP.net websites. The problem is that the whole page including all the divs are switched and have different CSS. Can I still use App_LocalResourcses? or do I need some other code to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggesting you that don't create separate pages you can translate pages and set related content that is not words similar images by checking special django language flags, similar `get_current_language_bidi` or `get_current_language` and others...

example in template:

```
...
{% get_current_language_bidi as LANGUAGE_BIDI %}
{% ifequal LANGUAGE_BIDI 'rtl' %}
    <img src="arabic-header.png">
{% else %}
    <img src="english-header.png">
{% endifequal %}
...
```

Read more about [django translation flags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/translation/).